# Ms-Access Query only allows 255 characters

Tags: ms-access

I am running into an issue for one of my unbound textboxes. Some of my users send out long comments in their "Comment" box and in the database, it only shows 255 characters max. Here is my query to insert the data to the database. It is only the txtComment textbox that I am trying to change.

```
CurrentDb.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data(Date_IPA, Auditor, Area, Operator, Safely, LineClearance, PPE, VerifyDoc, GVI, CompBefore, NonConf, ProcSteps, Trained, Points, Comments) " & _
    "VALUES ('" & Me.txt_Date.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Name.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Area.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Operator.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_Safe.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_LC.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_PPE.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_VDP.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_GVI.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_CBF.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_NC.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_ProStep.Value & "', '" & Me!cb_TrainProc.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Points.Value & "', '" & Me!txt_Comment.Value & "')"


btn_Clear_Click
```

Can anyone help me figuring this out please? Thanks!

Comment: Is Comments field a Memo (Long Text) type? Why not using a bound form?

Comment: I'm new to Access and not sure what you mean?

Comment: And date values must be properly formatted: `"VALUES ("" & Format(Me.txt_Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, '"`.

Comment: What I mean about what - bound form? If form is bound to table no code is needed to save data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the data type saved to "Short text" rather than "long text" now it works flawlessly!

Comment: Did you fix the date values? Are you saving dates to a date/time type field?

Comment: I am just leaving the date as a string. My program will run the data from the table and convert it to date/time format. Thanks for your help though!